# How can I write this code elegantly using vuejs directive or component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm finding way to write this code more elegantly using any vuejs option.

```
<a href="#" @click="editDocument(document)" v-if="permissions.canUpdateDocument">
    {{ document.title }}
</a>
<template v-else>
    {{ document.title }}
</template>
```

My first choice was simple vuejs component, I made it and the result was like this:

```
<href @click="editDocument(document)" can="canUpdateDocuments">
    {{ document.title }}
</href>
```

I am not quite satisfied with the solution. I think that could be solved using vuejs directive. The result would be like this one:

```
<a href="#" @click="editDocument(document)" v-can="canUpdateDocuments">
    {{ document.title }}
</a>
```

Is this possible?

Any other suggestion?

Comment: First of all change that anchor to a button or something else. You might also want to use `@click.prevent` on it. Then simply handle the permissions in your `editDocument` method. If the user is allowed to edit it, great, otherwise nope. This way you re-cycle a lot of the code in one simple method.

Comment: @techouse Here I want an anchor, not button. I agree, I should use `@click.prevent`. About permission, I can do it like you suggested, but I'll still have an anchor if the user has no permission. If user doesn't have permission I want to show him/her simple text `document.title`, without anchor.

Comment: What's the point of having an anchor then? Simply use a span or something. The anchor is pretty much useless since you override its native behaviour with `@click.prevent` and as you've just pointed out, if the user has no permission, it should only be text, which again makes absolutely no case for using an anchor.

Comment: You could create a global mixin and use it like ```v-if="can(canUpdateDocuments)"```

Comment: @techouse Thank you man, sometime we don't see obvious and simple solution. The point of using anchor was to get its default styling. Normally, I can easy set anchor styling on span element. Depending on user permission it will be like anchor or as plain text.

Comment: @PredragRakonjac Hehe, glad it's sorted.